# How to set -xnohup option on JAVA_OPTIONS

Tags: java, linux, weblogic12c

I've read from these articles [1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm) and this [2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html) that I need to set -xnohup option on JAVA_OPTIONS when starting weblogic. In order to avoid this error

**Error**

```
####<Sep 7, 2012 3:14:20 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <Ncorp-PLM-08> <Ncorp-PLM-08-AgileServer> <Thread-1> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1347011060768> <BEA-000388> <JVM called WLS shutdown hook. The server will force shutdown now>

####<Sep 7, 2012 3:14:20 PM IST> <Alert> <WebLogicServer> <Ncorp-PLM-08> <Ncorp-PLM-08-AgileServer> <Thread-1> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1347011060768> <BEA-000396> <Server shutdown has been requested by <WLS Kernel>>
```

However I can't find where in setDomain.sh I need to place -Xnohup. I am using oracle weblogic 12c and oracle linux.
Java version

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Appreciate if anyone can help.

## update

I placed Xnohup option on setDomain.sh but encountered the below error

```
Unrecognized option: -Xnohup
```

From setDomainEnv.sh I added the option in this part of the script.

```
JAVA_PROPERTIES="${JAVA_PROPERTIES} ${WLP_JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
export JAVA_PROPERTIES

JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${JAVA_PROPERTIES} -Xnohup"
```

Comment: check setEnv.sh script too you have to find JAVA_OPTIONS=... that is the place

Comment: hi vadim, i couldn't find a script named setEnv.sh however I found setStartupEnv.sh but there is no JAVA_OPTIONS inside the file.

Comment: I'm sorry, looked at my local modified install... Originally it is in SetDomainEnv.sh.  And there are many places where you can do it. Starting from setting JAVA_OPTIONS system variable before start weblogic.

Comment: hi vadim, updated my question. i did try to add xnohup on setDomainEnv.sh but encountered an error. Can you specify where I can actually place it? I tried placing it in different places but still I encountered xnohup not recognized

Answer (score 1):

It seems like problem is not in that parameters at all.
Also you missed in articles that:

> -Xrs
>   Note:
>   -Xrs is a **non-standard** option in HotSpot JVM. JRockit JVM continues to support this option; however, the JRockit JVM **nonstandard** options -Xnohup and -XX:+|-ReduceSignalUsage provide the same functionality.

It's more like a problem about how Weblogic started. It seems like you start it from regular user terminal, then logout. It should be kind of background process.

Comment: Sorry, nohup is a command in Unix, not a JVM parameter. try this > nohup startWebLogic.sh

Comment: hi vadim, thanks for the reply. I used -Xrs arguments in place of nohup and I didn't get any error so far. also when starting weblogic or nodemanagers i also used nohup startWeblogic.sh /dev/null 2>&1 &. I'll try to observe if I still encounter any errors or if it will shutdown automatically